# security - rubber-ducky-attacks - How to block only a part of the USB ports from delivering mouse/keyboard input?

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse, security, blacklist

I want to secure a system against USB rubber ducky attacks because I know they are really common, and I don't want to have to rely on me never making any mistakes here, although I'll try.

I watched this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tJJDZV1XSzo

And it suggested to generally disable USB keyboard/mouse input via some blacklisting mechanism...

My question is: Can I use the same or similar mechanisms to disable USB keyboard/mouse input only on certain USB ports?

Comment: "really common"?

Comment: yesss at least the guy in the video and other resources suggest this...

Comment: Also rubber ducky attack is quite simple, so it seems plausible it's hacker's favorite.
Afaik even that Saudi-Arabian Uranium enrichment plant was hacked this way... So even professionals use this type of attack... I don't want to have to deal with these...

Comment: Seems already answered at https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/173869/how-to-stop-usb-rubber-ducky

Comment: I already know how I could stop this kind of attack. blacklisting all usb ports for usage as mouse/keyboard. However, I don't want this, for obvious reasons, since I use USB mouse&keyboard. I want to know how I can implement a specific way to stop the rubber ducky, by blacklisting some USB ports (using the OS's features only) and using only them for rubber duckies. I chose this way because I don't trust these shady softwares that say they "stop the rubber ducky", because I am (just like the author of the question you mentioned) not shure whether these work and I am not shure that theyre safe.

Comment: So no, @user535733 I don't think that the question is already answered, because all the answers to the other question don't seem satisfying to me, since most require shady software (of which I don't even know if it will always be fast enough, or even always detect the intrusion) to be installed (which I also don't want for other obvious reasons) on my device, and one proposes stripping the main user of its admin powers, which I think is a good idea, but still no 100% protection because I can't assure the attacker can't escalate their privileges exploiting malconfigurations.

Comment: So yes, definitely still looking for an answer that works not maybe and not 90%, but surely and 100%. And, most importantly, without disabling my USB mouse&keyboard, if I were fine with disabling them, I'd have the answer already. (Maybe I gonna post this approach to security stack exchange, since the other answers there aint the best.)

Comment: You feel you are threatened to have these attacks on you.

Comment: I'm not an especially valuable target, but in the world of hacking, why should you leave a snack that you could get for free? And I may definitely be careless enough to forget about security policies one day and plug in an insecure rubber ducky. The threat is actually myself + opportunists leveraging my mistakes @David.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the packages `usbauth` or `usbguard` to use the Linux kernel's USB authorization mechanism and the `bolt` or `thunderbolt-tools` packages to use the Linux kernel's Thunderbolt authorization mechanism.

Alas, 20.04 LTS's version of `usbguard` has removed the excellent Qt applet that made it very easy to use.